# JNI crashlog: source file line determination with stacktrace output

Tags: android, java-native-interface, crash-reports, debug-symbols

Crashes & ANR section of google play developer console provides this kind of feedback when native code crashes on user's device:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: '...'
Revision: '...'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: ...., tid: ...., name: ....  >>> com.package <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
<registers>
backtrace:
    #00 pc 003ba9be  /data/app/com.package/lib/arm/libx.so (sl_setVolumeSound(unsigned int, float)+105)
    #01 pc 003b9db7  /data/app/com.package/lib/arm/libx.so (Audio::setVolumeSound(unsigned int, float)+106)
```

so far, so good. But how could one determine a source code line out of bytecode offset(?), such as +105 for the sl_setVolumeSound function in the sample output above?

I would especially appreciate a solution which would work completely in macosx command line, with no IDEs engaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ndk-stack`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html) is specially suited for this purpose. Note, that to get it working you need a non-stripped versions of your native libraries. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276799/how-to-use-ndk-stack-with-shared-library-in-aar-file/40278937#40278937).

Comment: Exactly what I've searched for, thank you! Pointing to obj/local/armeabi/*.so unstripped library is also saved a lot of my time. Looks like I can't do much right now, have to update jenkins scripts to archive this unstripped .so lib along with further releases