# How to use ndk-stack with shared library in AAR file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm using shared object libraries in Android application. These shared object libraries are in `.aar` file.

One of library is crashing. In order to check crash logs and exact line no. I am using `ndk-stack` took.

Usage of `ndk-stack` is

```
$ adb logcat |  ndk-stack -sym <Path to  your shared libraries>
```

Now How can I get a path of shared libraries in AAR file?

Answer (score 9):

You should keep in mind that not every `.so` file is useful for `ndk-stack`. Android NDK produces two kinds of `.so` files: stripped and non-stripped. The most difference is that last ones contain debug information, that is needed for `ndk-stack` and first ones don't. `readelf` may help to check if particular file is stripped or not:

```
$ readelf <non-stripped-lib> -S | grep debug
  [23] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 00302c 0052d9 00      0   0  1
  [24] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 008305 000879 00      0   0  1
  [25] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 008b7e 001aa7 00      0   0  1
  [26] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 00a628 000088 00      0   0  8
  [27] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 00a6b0 0000d0 00      0   0  1
  [28] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 00a780 0009de 00      0   0  1
  [29] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 00b15e 002387 01  MS  0   0  1
  [30] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 00d4e8 0003d0 00      0   0  4
$

$ readelf <stripped-lib> -S | grep debug
$
```

As you see not-stripped ELF has a lot of `.debug_*` sections, that indeed contain line numbers, private / static function names, etc.

Next, `.aar` files, both debug and release ones, has only **stripped** binaries. So they are useless for `ndk-stack`.

AFAIK, the only place where non-stripped binaries may be found is a `obj/` dir. Its location depends slightly on used build system:

- for `ndk-build` it is under `<module_name>/build/intermediates/ndk`
- for `CMake`-based it is under `<module_name>/build/intermediates/cmake`

Also it looks like out-of-the-box android gradle plugin offers no way to pack unstripped libraries to your `aar`, so the only way here is some custom task in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Another vote for someone to show how to use the cmake based system & aars with ndk-stack.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I've updated answer a bit. Though it didn't reveal some conceptually new.