# How to get stacktraces of JNI Native crashes

Tags: java, android, debugging, java-native-interface, crash-reports

How to get stacktraces of JNI Native crashes. `debuggerrd` stores stacktraces in tombstones, but how can I programatically get stacktraces of where the Native code crashed ?

The problem is the android app crashes at client end, for which I want to know atleast from where the crash has originated. Tombstones have perfect collection of crash data for my use, but dunno how to send those via network.

How does Android expect us to debug when they put up somany restrictions on READ_LOGS, LogCat logs, Tombstones, blocking JAVA calls from Native Signal Handlers, blocking adb bugreport execution from application etc etc .. :smh:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the device or only the bug report?

Comment: I don't want to trouble the client as much as possible. Lets assume that we don't have access to the device.

Comment: Ok yeah, makes sense. I was going to suggest dmesg however you would need access to the device. Not entirely sure otherwise. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think ndk-stack might be the right tool for this. More details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276799/how-to-use-ndk-stack-with-shared-library-in-aar-file/40278937#40278937).

Comment: What ? How? I still don't understand the link :(